# Finding ContiguousCount of items in list?

Tags: python, list, counter, contiguous

Given a list:

```
>>> l = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x']
```

I could get the count of the list by using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'x': 3, 'y': 2})
```

**How can I count contiguous items instead of the global count of the elements in the list?** E.g.

```
>>> l = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x']
>>> ContiguousCounter(l)
[('x',2), ('y',2), ('x', 1)]

>>> l = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y']
>>> ContiguousCounter(l)
[('x',2), ('y',2), ('x', 3), ('y', 1)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use built-in [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function:

```
In [3]: from itertools import groupby

In [4]: l = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x']

In [5]: list(groupby(l))
Out[5]: 
[('x', <itertools._grouper at 0x7fd94716f1d0>),
 ('y', <itertools._grouper at 0x7fd94716f208>),
 ('x', <itertools._grouper at 0x7fd94716f240>)]

In [6]: [(x, len(list(g))) for x, g in groupby(l)]
Out[6]: [('x', 2), ('y', 2), ('x', 1)]
```